# Switch without cases (but with default) in System.Linq.Expressions

Tags: c#, .net, linq-expressions

I have tried to create a switch expression with System.Linq.Expressions:

```
var value = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
var defaultBody = Expression.Constant(0);
var cases1 = new[] { Expression.SwitchCase(Expression.Constant(1), Expression.Constant(1)), };
var cases2 = new SwitchCase[0];
var switch1 = Expression.Switch(value, defaultBody, cases1);
var switch2 = Expression.Switch(value, defaultBody, cases2);
```

but in the last line I get an ArgumentException:

> Non-empty collection required. Parameter name: cases

What is the reason of this exception? May be this a bug in [Expression.Switch(…)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/SwitchExpression.cs,205)?

In a C# a switch with "default" part only is correct:

```
switch(expr) {
default:
  return 0;
}//switch
```

**UPD**: I have submitted [an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1877) to the CoreFX repo on GitHub

Comment: What is the goal of such a construction? `switch` with `default` and no  `case` would just execute `default`

Comment: For me switch without cases looks pretty meaningless, so I think this exception is reasonable.

Comment: Yes, the C# spec says a  switch-block has of zero or more switch-sections; but that doesn't mean that a switch expression has to confom to the C# spec. Since you create the expression at runtime, you could, as a workaround, simply add an `Expression.SwitchCase` with a value that is !=  switch value; or add the body of the default case as a switch case with value = switch value.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev while I can't think of much of a reason to have the C# equivalent, I could certainly see how this would be useful when creating a switch dynamically; if you are going to have a variable number of `SwitchCase`s depending on some criteria, you don't have to special-case the condition of their being zero.

Comment: @JonHanna Yes, this is exactly my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a complete analogy between C#'s `switch` and `SwitchExpression`. In the other direction, consider that you can have:

```
var value = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
var meth = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, string>>(
  Expression.Switch(
    value,
    Expression.Call(value, typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString")),
    Expression.SwitchCase(Expression.Constant("Zero"), Expression.Constant(0, typeof(int))),
    Expression.SwitchCase(Expression.Constant("One"), Expression.Constant(1, typeof(int)))),
    value
  ).Compile();
Console.WriteLine(meth(0)); // Zero
Console.WriteLine(meth(1)); // One
Console.WriteLine(meth(2)); // 2
```

Here the `SwitchExpression` returns a value which is something `switch` cannot do.

So, just as being able to do something with `SwitchExpression` does not mean you can do it with a `switch`, so too there's no reason to assume that being able to do something with a `switch` means you can do it with a `SwitchExpression`.

That said, I see no good reason why `SwitchExpression` was set this way, except perhaps that it simplifies the case where an expression has no cases **and** no default body. That said, I think this was likely just a matter of the expression being generally intended to have multiple cases, and that was what it was coded to support.

<s>I've [submitted a pull-request to .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/2803) that would allow such case-less expressions, by producing a `SwitchExpression` where the default value for the type of `switchValue` has the same body as the default body. This approach means anything that would be surprised by a `SwitchExpression` with no cases should still cope, avoiding backwards-compatibility issues. The case of there being no default either is dealt with by creating a noop expression that does nothing, so the only case that now still throws an `ArgumentException` is if there is no case **and** no default **and** the type is explicitly set to something other than `void`, this case being invalid under the typing rules that must obviously still be kept.</s>

[Update: That approach was rejected, but [a later pull-request](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/5547) was accepted, so case-less `SwitchExpression`s are now allowed by .NET Core, though if and when that is adopted by other versions of .NET is another matter].

In the meantime, or if you use another version of .NET, you're best-off using a helper method like:

```
public static Expression SwitchOrDefault(Type type, Expression switchValue, Expression defaultBody, MethodInfo comparison, IEnumerable<SwitchCase> cases)
{
  if (cases != null)
  {
    // It's possible that cases is a type that can only be enumerated once.
    // so we check for the most obvious condition where that isn't true
    // and otherwise create a ReadOnlyCollection. ReadOnlyCollection is
    // chosen because it's the most efficient within Switch itself.
    if (!(cases is ICollection<SwitchCase>))
      cases = new ReadOnlyCollection<SwitchCase>(cases);
    if (cases.Any())
      return Switch(type, switchValue, defaultBody, comparison, cases);
  }
  return Expression.Block(
    switchValue, // include in case of side-effects.
    defaultBody != null ? defaultBody : Expression.Empty() // replace null with a noop expression.
  );
}
```

Overloads like:

```
public static Expression SwitchOrDefault(Expression switchValue, Expression defaultBody, params SwitchCase[] cases)
{
  return SwitchOrDefault(switchValue, defaultBody, null, (IEnumerable<SwitchCase>)cases);
}
```

And so on can then be added.

This results in a trimmer `Expression` overall than my pull-request, because it cuts out the `switch` entirely in the no-cases case and just returns the default body. If you **really** need to have a `SwitchExpression` then you could create a similar helper method that follows the same logic as that pull-request does in creating a new `SwitchCase` and then using that.